# Partially defined target for supervised neural network training in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, training-data, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have a question relating to partially supervised training of neural networks using MATLAB (and the neural network toolbox).

I have a neural net that has two output layers: one 'final' layer at the end of a feedforward network, and one middle layer within said network.

I am training the network via the final layer using labeled data (targets), but I'd also like to put an output constraint on the middle output layer (as follows in the next paragraph). In short summary, I'd like to supervise training of the middle layer only some of the time (known times), and let it train supervised to a target (zeros) the rest of the time.

Here are the details:

When the final layer target is in a specific state 'A', the middle layer is trained to be certain different target values (zeros in my case), however when the final layer target is in other states ('B', 'C', 'D', etc), the middle layer has no target and learns 'unsupervised' to the values the training sees fit.

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB? e.g. Can I define targets to be partially undefined?

I have been reading around semi-supervised learning, but this seems to pertain to something different and carries over assumptions based off the supervised training part, which I don't want to do here.

This question is trying to solve the problem of "how to do I make my middle layer zeros when my final layer is zeros?". Perhaps there is an easier way to achieve this than what I'm posing above. e.g. have only positive transfer functions between the middle layer and final layer. I'd like to hear your thoughts if you have any other ideas!

Look forward to your replies and thanks in advance!

best, Rob

Comment: Hi, Found the answer. Use 'nan' in the output